# SSH refuses connection on CentOS after changing permissions on /etc

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty

I'm really a newbie in the Linux World. I've made change on a CentOS 5.4 server with this command :

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /etc
```

Now when I try to connect with Putty from a Windows computer, I get this error :

```
server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

I assume the SSH service is running because I've currently another SSH session, that was open before the change, that is already alive. (connected as root)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `/var/log/secure` where you should see the errors.

The files in `/etc/ssh/` can't be writable by the others. And some of them can't be even readable by others (private keys). Fix it such as:

```
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key
chmod 644 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub /etc/ssh/ssh_config /etc/ssh/moduli
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Succeeded but with 600 on the first line, not 640.

Comment: Yes, might be on the old RHEL6. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: We speek here of a server just used for Asterisk (internally). Asterisk was not affected by this problem. Do you think I can consider the machine as stable ? Will it reboot safely ?

Comment: There might be other issues with different configuration files. But the ssh should start successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You just broke system-wide permissions and you're not allowed to login from security reasons. Try checking logs from /var/log/messages and /var/log/auth.log

```
grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log
```

You won't fix it easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This commands returns "no such file"

Comment: What about `grep 'sshd' /var/log/security`?

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Try connecting to the server with `-v` - verbose flag on... It doesn't look good.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "Try connecting to the server with -v"

Comment: When you're connecting to remote server sshd can give you more verbose log messages that are hidden by default by your ssh client. It can contain your error message and its reason. If you have access to linux machine you would do `ssh -vvv ...` to enable verbose messages. I don't know how to do it on windows. Can you login from server to server with `ssh -vvv YOURUSER@localhost`  (run this on server) from existing session.

Comment: debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: Yup, now we know what's wrong, you can fix this problem with this http://superuser.com/a/215506 solution